# How do I tune this regex to return the matches I want?

Tags: ruby, regex

So I have a string that looks like this:

```
@jackie@test.com, @mike@test.com
```

What I want to do is before any email in this comma separated list, I want to remove the `@`. The issue I keep running into is that if I try to do a regular `\A` flag like so `/[\A@]+/`, it finds all the instances of `@` in that string...including the middle crucial `@`.

The same thing happens if I do `/[\s@]+/`. I can't figure out how to just look at the beginning of each string, where each string is a complete email address.

**Edit 1**

Note that all I need is the regex, I already have the rest of the stuff I need to do what I want. Specifically, I am achieving everything else like this:

```
str.gsub(/@/, '').split(',').map(&:strip)
```

Where `str` is my string.

All I am looking for is the regex portion for my `gsub`.

Comment: How about `' '.concat(s).gsub(/\s+@/,' ')`? Insert `+` after  `@` if `@@jackie@test.com` is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the below negative lookbehind based regex.

```
str.gsub(/(?<!\S)@/, '').split(',').map(&:strip)
```

`(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind asserts that the character or substring we are going to match would be preceeded by any but not of a non-space character. So this matches the `@` which exists at the start or the `@` which exists next to a space character.

Difference between my answer and hwnd's `str.gsub(/\B@/, '')` is, mine won't match the `@` which exists in `:@` but hwnd's answer does. `\B` matches between two word characters or two non-word characters.

Comment: Can you explain what a `below negative lookbehind` is? This seems intriguing.

Comment: Awesome. Looks good. Yet to test, but intuitively this makes sense.

Comment: Added what the diff between mine and hwnd's. Just pick the one you want.

Comment: Can we use this regex in split also?

Comment: Why would I need to use `:@`? That doesn't ever appear in an email. Are you talking about a theoretical case of when that may appear, or is there an edge case with email addresses I am overlooking?

Comment: @marcamillion I just explained the difference in common.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks either way. Since @hwnd hasn't added one, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution

```
str = "@jackie@test.com, @mike@test.com"
p str.split(/,[ ]+/).map{ |i| i.gsub(/^@/, '')}
```

Output

```
["jackie@test.com", "mike@test.com"]
```

Comment: I actually have the rest of the ruby. It's much simpler - `str.gsub(/@/, '').split(',').map(&:strip)`. What I really need is the regex that I put in the `gsub`. Ideas?

Comment: You could probably just use a non-word boundary here: `str.gsub(/\B@/, '')`

Comment: @marcamillion  I update my answer based on your code, but had to move gsub to end.

Comment: This looks cool, but I would rather not use a double `map`. @hwnd That works perfectly. If you want to add an answer I will accept it. Thanks for trying Wand-Maker.

Comment: @hwnd Ofcourse that flag wouldn't be available on Rubular :(